# How to use two interrogatives in one sentence

Tags: relative-clauses, questions

Does the following sentence make sense?

> I took a survey on how many cars **of which color** were sold last month.

For example, this survey says that five red cars were sold, three black cars were sold, ....

I am not sure whether the "of which color" is correct.

Could you please explain why this expression may be wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't the question be phrased as "I took a survey on how many cars of which color**s** (or, possibly, **what colors**) were sold last month."

Comment: Please note that [English Language & Usage Stack Exchange is a question and answer site *for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts*](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour). All of your 4 Qs on this forum have been very basic and would be better suited to our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), to which one of your Qs has already been moved.

Comment: I'm sorry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 3):

Neither "which color" nor "what color" sound right to me. How about:

> I took a survey on how many cars of *each* colour were sold last month.